# internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a bug report

Tags: python, android, buildozer

Buildozer failed to execute the last command ,I added a full log with log_level = 2,but it does not go, I can not understand and fix the problem, I am working on a MacBook Pro 2015 with macOS Monterey version 12.4 and 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5 dual-core processor, I have read that with new updates to problems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.